# Smallest subet of nodes that reach all nodes in DAG

Tags: algorithm

Say we have a DAG comprised of a list of nodes A, B, C, D, and E.

Each node has a list of reachable nodes - for example:

```
A --> B, C
A --> B
D --> E
```

In this case, we would have to visit nodes A and D to comprehensively visit all nodes in the graph.  What is the best algorithm to approach this problem in general?

Comment: This network may help you better: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Doesn't almost all "algorithm" category questions belong to CS site then? I admit these sites and their scope really confuse me

Comment: This is the problem of  minimum spanning tree applied to a directed graph.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a linear approach:

1. For every node count it`s in-degree (number of edges pointing to it)
2. Because graph is a DAG (no cycles) we can just take all nodes with in-degree of 0 as our starting sub-set

Time Complexity(N + M) - linear in graph size

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

Let's say that node `A` is **parent** of node `B` if there is an arc from `A` to `B`.
And node `C` is the **most-parent** of node `B`, if it has no **parent** and there is a path from `C` to `B`.

1. Mark every node as `not visited`.
2. For every node in DAG you define it's parent.
3. for every node `A` that is `not visited`

   4. Find `A`'s most-parent `MP`
   5. Mark all nodes that are reachable from `MP` as `visited`
   6. Put `MP` to `array`

After this you'll get smallest subset of nodes that reach all nodes in DAG in `array`

Time compexity of algo is `O(n^2)`